Disable tenants in multi tenant SaaS app
I am building an app where I have tenants and each tenant can have multiple users. The users can do multiple things in the application and these functionalities also are kind of independent from each other but they all require a logged in user. For the user accounts I am using keycloak with an attribute "tenant" to have the tenantId inside the access tokens. But lets say I want to deactivate a tenant (e.g. he didn't pay the subscription fee), how would I implement it the best way?
I thought of disabling every keycloak user connected to that tenant. That way they are not allowed to log in anymore and the api endpoints are protected from them. But I think based on the number of users inside a tenant this can lead to "errors" e.g. one user was not correctly disabled.
Another thought was to check for each api request, whether the tenant (I can get that from the access token) is activated. But for this I have to program this check on every api request. I have some tenantmanagement component that is responsible for creating the tenants and this would also have information about the status of the tenant. But I am not sure how to check for every request made, if the user belongs to a deactivated tenant or not.
Is there some best practice or real world examples on open source projects where I can get inspiration for the solution to this problem?
EDIT: The techstack is java and spring boot with spring security. Another thought would be to check in the spring securityFilterChain whether the belonging tenant is active or not. This way I wont have to implement a check on each Rest api endpoint. But the security Filter would have a dependency to the tenant component.

The normal way to implement such a check in a Java webapp would be with a HttpFilter. Implement it once, configure (in web.xml or equivalent) and it gets applied to all relevant calls the the server. If the tenant is disabled, the call is short-circuited and an appropriate response is sent (e.g., 403).

I think we need to know why its bad to check on every request? presumably you are pulling data for the tennantId anyway, so an extra check isn't going to impact performance, plus you can cache

Also, presumably you are gona want some nice message, not just a 500, maybe a phased switch off where they get reduced functionality etc etc

If you don't want to do it on every Web request, you could look into implementing a keycloack extension to check at authorization time if the tenant is enabled.

What should happen to users that are active using the service at the moment the associated tenant gets deactivated? Should they be denied access immediately or on the next login/token refresh?
